# Problem in output of CS50 week 2 Problem set readability

Tags: c, cs50, readability

The code is ment to take user input, then compute how many words, letters and sentences are in the input. Then calculate the index.

index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8
Where L = average number of letters per hundred words and S is the average number of sentences per 100 words in the text.

if the index is in less than one print "below grade 1" and if it is greater than 16 print "greater than 16". and anything in between should be grade __ (where __ = the index number), For example, if index number = 12. Print grade 12.

In my case the code seems to only be showing the correct output for grades less than 1 and more than 16 and ignoring the other cases.

More details and inputs to the problem here - https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/2/readability/

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int count_sentances(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int Grade_level(int i, int j, int k);


int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text = ");

    int num_letters = count_letters(text);
    int num_sentances = count_sentances(text);
    int num_words = count_words(text);
    int gradeLevel = Grade_level(num_letters, num_sentances, num_words);


    if (gradeLevel < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (gradeLevel > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade level %d\n", gradeLevel);
    }

}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
    {
        letters++;
    }
    }
    return letters;
}

int count_sentances(string text)
{
    int sentances = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '.'|| text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
        {
            sentances++;
        }
    }
    return sentances;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int words = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
        words++;
        }
    }
    return words;
}

int Grade_level(int num_letters, int num_words, int num_sentances)
{
    float index, L, S;

    L = (num_letters/num_words) * 100;
    S = (num_sentances/num_words) * 100;

    index = (0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8;

    index = round(index);

    return (int)index;

}
```

Comment: The expression `(num_letters/num_words) * 100` is an all-integer expression with an integer result. Same with the next one.

Comment: Also, you almost never need to use `float` for floating point values. Use `double` instead.